# JQuery Ajax Get Customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using one of the many options defined at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (or anywhere else) can I map the incoming data to a specific data type rather than the default generic object that is usually returned?

My usual method is to "convert" the generated object by grabbing each property and placing it into the constructor for the new object that I really want to use.  Then, I just forget about the old object.  I would imagine that there is a much more efficient way to do this.

I came up with/found a few ideas such as simply adding methods to each of the returned objects.  It works well, but I just have to know if there is an even more efficient method.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you desire?

Comment: Did you try setting the `dataType` option? You could also try a [custom data type](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/#handling-custom-data-types).

Comment: @simshaun I think Na7coldwater explains it pretty well.  Check out the first part of his answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're saying that you have code like the following:

```
function Pirate(name, hasParrot)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.hasParrot = hasParrot;
}
```

and the server is sending this JSON data:

```
{
  name: "Blackbeard",
  hasParrot: true
}
```

which jQuery is converting to a plain object, right?
If that's the case, you can use a [custom datatype](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/#handling-custom-data-types) to parse the server's data directly into a Pirate object, like so:

```
// First define the converter:
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  converters: {
    "json pirate": function(obj) {
      if(!obj.name || typeof obj.hasParrot === "undefined")
      {
        throw "Not a valid Pirate object!";
      }
      else
      {
        return new Pirate(obj.name, obj.hasParrot);
      }
    }
  }
}
// Then use it!
$.ajax("http://example.com/getPirate", {
  data: {id: 20},
  dataType: "pirate",
  success: function(pirate){
    console.log(pirate instanceof Pirate); // Should be true
  }
});
```

Edit: If you really want to skip the step of converting to JSON, you could could replace `"json pirate"` above with `"text pirate"` and write your own parser for the raw text returned by the ajax call.

Comment: Haha, I like this example, but I'm thinking this is about the same amount of work for the browser/device as what I normally do.  It looks like it still parses the json string as a generic object and passes the values stored in that object into a new instance of another object type.  I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to get ajax to parse the json string directly into the pirate object.  It seems like you understood my question, though.  Considering I typed it out right after a long day at work, I'm surprised anyone got it.

Comment: @BDawg I edited my answer to include instructions for converting directly from the raw text.

Comment: Ha! Beautiful!  You, sir, have won.  Thank you very much!